# drop-list is keeping slideup and down many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery drop-list is keeping slideup and down many times

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <img src="img/logo.jpg"> 
    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#"> Product 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> product 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">product 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">product 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">product 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    $("li").has(".dropdown").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find(".dropdown").slideDown();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find(".dropdown").slideUp();
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are hovering in and out of the Products item multiple times in quick succession, the slideDown and slideUp animations get queued. Call [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to cancel the current animation before doing a new slideDown or slideUp:

```
$("li").has(".dropdown").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find(".dropdown").stop().slideDown();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find(".dropdown").stop().slideUp();
    }
);
```